# Running Ionic framework results in error Could not reserve enough space for object heap

Tags: java, ionic-framework, heap-memory

I am trying to build simple application with Ionic Framework. When I run:

`ionic build android`

I get this error:

```
[dx] Error occurred during initialization of VM
[dx] Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\Admin\android-sdks\tools\ant\build.xml:892: The following error occurre
d while executing this line:
C:\Users\Admin\android-sdks\tools\ant\build.xml:894: The following error occurre
d while executing this line:
C:\Users\Admin\android-sdks\tools\ant\build.xml:906: The following error occurre
d while executing this line:
C:\Users\Admin\android-sdks\tools\ant\build.xml:283: null returned: 1

Total time: 4 seconds
```

How can I fix this. (I am using Ionic 1.2.3, this happened after ionic update)

Answer (score 1):

go to your `C:\Users\<username>\.gradle` directory; find the `gradle.properties` file, if there is no such file, just create one. Finally, edit the `gradle.properties` file, add `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx512m` to it.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, here is how to fix it:
Go to Start->Control Panel->System->Advanced(tab)->Environment Variables->System Variables->New:
Variable name: _JAVA_OPTIONS
Variable value: -Xmx512M